# Javafx crashes on OSX on JRE 1.8

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

Project: https://github.com/gadelkareem/aws-client

Intellij-build: https://github.com/gadelkareem/aws-client/releases/tag/v0.0.2-alpha

Maven-build: https://github.com/gadelkareem/aws-client/releases/tag/v0.0.3-alpha

Building Artifact works my system but crashes on other systems. I tried to build using Intellij ant build.xml and maven javafx plugin `mvn jfx:native`

Running AwsClient.app on OSX El Capitan Vmware image crashes with this log report: https://github.com/gadelkareem/aws-client/releases/download/v0.0.3-alpha/hs_err_pid861.log even after installing JRE 1.8

I also tried other JavaFX projects and they also crash with the same error.

*Update*

Bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146952

Comment: Posting bug reports isn't very effective here. Best use the official java bug tracker.

Comment: I am still not sure if it is a bug or something wrong with the deploy process as I am new to Java in general. Please advice if this is a bug

Comment: If you get a hotspot error, and you aren't adding any of your own native code, it's a java bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out that [VMware is not a certified hypervisor](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html). I also tested on Parallels and VirtualBox using

```
java -Dprism.order=sw -jar AwsClient.jar
```

which rendered the application partially on VirtualBox but still got error

```
CGLCreateContext error: 10002
```